# Macbook El Capitan won't shut down

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, macos

some time ago I ran into problem, sometimes when i try to shut down mac it won't shut down loading wheel is just spinning and I have to shut down with the button. I tried SMC and PRAM reset, the problem keeps occurring. I am guessing it's some kind of problem with the apps, because it happens EVERY time if i press ,,reopen apps'' at the shutdown pop-up (when it happens only sometimes without that box checked). How can I solve this problem?

P.S. I don't have Parallels installed, I know it sometimes causes the problem.

Comment: I always get in the habit of quitting all open apps before I shutdown my computers. Sometimes I find that apps with files open on servers (hard-wired or cloud) can take a while to close and I can act on this manually instead of having OS X choke on it.

Comment: I tend to agree with @IconDaemon. Additionally, what apps are open when this happens? If they're large (or have large files opened) then it is extremely plausible that it's taking a very long time to write the complicated memory of that app to the disk. If the disk is full or nearly full, that will only make things worse.

Comment: That's not the case, disk is almost empty, also It shouldn't take forever to write files to new, empty SSD. Also quitting all apps manually sometimes doesn't change a thing (mac still freezes with wheel at shutdown)

Comment: Did the spinning wheel ever resolve itself and actually shutdown the MacBook? Are there any external devices connected to the USB | T-bolt | FireWire ports? Any BlueTooth devices connected? Any Time Machine device (wifi or physical) connected? Any remote services (hard-wired or cloud) connected?

Comment: No it doesn't resolve itself I have to force quit with button every time. No USB, no bluetooth, from remote services - only Icloud

Comment: I have the same issue. Tried removing incompatible kexts and launchdaemons. No resolution yet though.

Comment: So no one knows the solution? I noticed that it helps when you use mac without plugged power cable (I guess SMC restart).  Should I check any kind of logs for a help?

Comment: In case anyone comes across this old issue, this solution seems to work for most (including me just now). https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/245194/1195